# Retrieve values from dynamic radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a table that has 3 columns. In the 3rd column there is a radiobuttonlist that the user uses to evaluate the similarity of columns 1 and 2. The table has 60+ rows and is created dynamically. All of that works like a charm. BUT: How can I read the radiobuttonlist (or rather the values that the user chose) after the submit? I have tried the following, but that doesn't work (all of which is in a form of course):

```
eval1 = new RadioButtonList();
eval1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Agree","1"));
eval1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Somewhat Agree","2"));
eval1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Disagree","3"));
eval1.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
this.Session["eval1"] = eval1;
```

When I submit this, the session var holds the radionbuttonlist, but no value is selected.

I tried to set AutoPostBack to true and that changed the behavior to what I need. But I don't want to reload the page every time the user chooses an option. This would mean 60+ reloads...

Any hints?

Comment: I think you have to create `RadioButtonList` every time when the page has postback.

Answer (score 0):

in place of:

this.Session["eval1"] = eval1;

use string array to store the values in the session.

Comment: At the time when this code runs, I don't have the values. Otherwise I could use the above code.

Answer (score 0):

This code is placed where?Maybe you should put it in the if (! IsPostBack ) {} try。For example

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
      eval1 = new RadioButtonList();
      eval1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Agree","1"));
      eval1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Somewhat Agree","2"));
      eval1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Disagree","3"));
      eval1.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
      this.Session["eval1"] = eval1;

}
```

Comment: It is in the Page_Load. I want to read the values on the "next" Page_Load where isPostBack is true.

Comment: @Jan  You must put code in the Page_Load if (! IsPostBack ) {}, otherwise the value will be covered in viewstate. so that you won't find any value.